# Retrieving Authorization and Token service from Office365 APIs

Tags: office365

I am currently developing an application that will be authenticating using the URLs we can retrieve from the Discovery service endpoints. The current way we are retrieving these is using the initial sign-in behavior, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations#Additionalresources). We are essentially querying `https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/FirstSignIn?redirect_uri={0}&scope={1}` with a redirect uri.

The issue is that this brings the user to a page which requires them to enter in their email, redirects back to us with the token and authorization service, and we then have to authenticate them using the service. Is there any way to bypass this initial sign in where we force the user to go to a separate page just to get these endpoints?

I found this endpoint looking around `https://api.office.com/discovery/emailhrd/getfederationprovider?domain=<domain>` but I don't see this documented anywhere. Can anyone point my to some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first sign in endpoint can be skipped if the app knows it only supports a certain account type. /FirstSignIn redirects to the right user auth endpoint depending if the account is a Microsoft Account (...@live.com, ...@outlook.com, ...@hotmail.com, etc) or if the account is a Microsoft Work or School account(aka Office 365 accounts, ...@tenant.onmicrosoft.com). If the app only supports one type of account, such that there is no need for disambiguation, then the app can choose to bypass /FirstSignIn and go directly to the authentication endpoint of the account type it supports.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx).
If you set this up, the administrator of the Office 365 organization need to log-in one-time and grant permissions that you have set in Azure Active Directory, afterwards there is no sign-in necessary anymore.

See also this link where this is explained in detail [Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx)